# What will happen if I delete the default VPC in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, amazon-vpc, vpc

I don't use the default VPC. I have created another VPC. However, I haven't assigned my other VPC as default. I would like to delete my default VPC and set my other VPC as default.

I read some arguments on the Internet. If I delete the default VPC then I will not be able to create instances. Is this correct?

What will happen if I delete the default VPC in AWS?

Comment: You can recreate the default VPC now. AWS documentation can be found here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/default-vpc.html#create-default-vpc

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know that. Quote from the document: "You cannot mark an existing nondefault VPC as a default VPC."

What will happen if I don't have any "default" VPC? Is it a problem?

Comment: There shouldn't be any problems if you delete the default VPC. You won't get the default settings (like a public IP when creating an EC2 instance) in the VPC you created unless you explicitly define it.

Answer (score 4):

AWS has recently announced a feature to self restore the default VPC.

Also its not mandatory to have a default VPC in place for a region. However, at least one is needed if you plan to start EC2 instances in the particular region.

Note: In the past, if the default VPC is deleted, it was required to contact AWS Support to restore it back.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, if there are no resources in your default VPC, and you delete it, nothing will happen. Any VPC other than the default will need to be "manually" selected and may not auto-populate for other services - there is no existing way (and no real need) to call another VPC the "default VPC", however.